# JQuery POST only adding record to mysql once

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm using JQuery to call a php script which will add a record to the mySQL database.

This works fine for the first time I try to add something, but if I want to add more records to the database, it will not add anything. There are no errors in the console or php error log. It does not work if I refresh or reopen the page either.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){

        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var repassword = $("#repassword").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var reemail = $("#reemail").val();

        if(password != repassword)
        {
            alert("Passwords do not match");
            return false; 

        }

        else if(email != reemail)
        {
            alert("Emails do not match");
            return false; 

        }

        else {

            $.post("signup_script.php",
            {
                username: username,
                password: username,
                email: email
            });
        }
    });
});
```

php:

```
<?php 

    include_once('profile_Functions.php');

    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    createUser($username,$password,$email);

?>
```

html:

```
<div class="body"></div>
    <div class="grad"></div>
    <div class="header">
        <div>odd<span>job</span></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="signup">

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="js/js_functions.js"></script>

<form  id ="myForm" action =""  method = "post" >
            <input   type="text" placeholder="username" id ="username" required = "required" maxlength = "15"><br>
            <input type ="email" placeholder = "email" id = "email" required = "required" maxlength = "50"><br>
            <input type ="email" placeholder = "re-enter email" id = "reemail" required = "required" maxlength = "50"><br>
            <input  type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" required = "required" pattern = "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}"><br>
            <input  type="password" placeholder="re-enter password" id ="repassword" required = "required"><br>
            <p class = "passwordreq">Password must:</p>
            <ol class = "passwordreq"> 
                <li>Have 10 characters</li>
                <li>Have one number</li>
                <li>Have one uppercase letter</li>
            </ol>
            <input type="submit" value="sign up" id ="submit"> 
            <input type="button" value="go back"  onclick="window.location='index.html'">
        </form>
```

insert function:

```
function setup(){
extract($_GET);
extract($_POST);
extract($_SERVER);

$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$passwd="";

$connect=mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd) or die("error connecting mysql server");
mysql_select_db('oddjob',$connect) or die("error accessing db");
}

function createUser($name, $pass, $email){
setup();
$hashed_password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "insert into profiles (UserName, Password, Email) values ('$name', '$hashed_password', '$email'); ";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

}
```

Comment: are dynamicly chaning html after ajax ?

Comment: No, I am not changing the html

Comment: please post the insert query/function

Comment: which error you get ?

Comment: @mattslone is right- post the insert query string. This is the issue.

Comment: added query, and @fico7489 there is no error

Comment: hm you maybe have turned off error reporting ?

Answer (score 0):

You should close your connection each time

```
mysql_close($connect)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the solution is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143475/652519. 
Can you add the error function to your post function? Like so:

```
$.post("signup_script.php",
        {
            username: username,
            password: username,
            email: email
        })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

Then we can see if there are errors that happen upon insert in the DB.